# query what libraries are on the host of the python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a jupyter notebook, I can fairly easily check with python code if some libraries are installed on the current kernel of the python notebook.

However there is also the "host" kernel which has its own python env (ie the python process that was launched when `jupyter notebook` was called). Depending on what libraries/extensions were installed on the host, it may not be possible to do specific things on the jupyter notebook client itself.

Is there a way to query what libraries/modules/extensions are installed on the host, from the "client" notebook ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you test `!pip list` or `!pip freeze`?

To list locally installed packages and their version # within a pipenv environment, cd into a pipenv project and enter the following command:

```
pipenv lock -r
```

Comment: !pip list returns whatever there is on the current kernel env in the notebok
!which python also returns whatever the current python kernel in the notebook

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `!pip list` to show the modules/libraries installed on the current env. But I don't think you can view extensions.

Comment: You also need to switch to the env you want to see the modules of.

Comment: yes but the question would then be: how do I switch to the env that is executing the jupyter notebook ?

Comment: well you can switch to the env on command prompt by typing 'workon {your_env}'

Comment: not so sure about jupiter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Please use `!pip list --local` or `!pip freeze --local` if you're using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

This could get you started:

```
import sys
import os
for i in sys.path:
    try:
        print("->", i, ":")
        print(repr(os.listdir(i or ".")))
    except Exception:
        print("can't list", i)
        pass
```

NOTE that my code isn't a complete solution, but it is a start. I will attempt to improve it shortly, but even as it is it may be immediately useful for you to develop your own solution.

What it doesn't do:

- it does not determine whether it found a python file or a directory containing a valid package or something that isn't either (i.e. is not 'import'-able)
- It skips over zipped packages (such as this item that could be in sys.path: /home/pyodide/lib/python39.zip)
- it does not attempt to find built-in packages (those that are compiled into Python itself). Most of those would be already loaded, so you will find them in `sys.modules`, though

If you need to test for individual packages, rather than get a whole list: you may be better off using 'import' inside a try/except statement:

```py
try:
    import something
except ImportError:
    pass
    # do what you want if the package isn't available
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you can run:

```py
help("modules")
```

Or you can use [**`pydoc`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) for your work:

```py
import pydoc
```

```py
!pydoc modules
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe !pip list should work- if not, then pydoc most likely would, see above.